# Writing to a 2 byte register from 1 byte registers

Tags: microcontroller, assembly, 8051

I am an assembly newbie and I am trying to write an assembly routine to write data to EEPROM of a 8051 variant. (Specifically, [AT89C51CC03](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc4182.pdf))

In the datasheet, it says that I need to write to the column latches first. For this, I need to fill DPTR register with the address I want to write (2 bytes). As I am working mainly with C, I needed a way to pass the address from C code to the assembly routine. The following link explains the convention:

http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/c51/c51_ap_parampassreg.htm

which says that pointer parameters are assigned to R2(MSB) and R1(LSB).

**My question is, how can I move the contents of these 1 byte registers to DPTR, which is a two byte register?** I have a feeling that if I use MOV, I will overwrite the first byte I have written. [And the instruction set manual only provides an example for passing immediate values, not from registers.](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/is51/is51_mov.htm)

Comment: It seems there're registers called DPH and DPL, which should be accessible in 8-bit mode http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/is51/is51_ov_cpu8051variants.htm and https://www.slideshare.net/thandaiah/8051-microcontroller-notes-continuous (starting page 20).

Comment: Then let me make it an answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems they're Special Function Registers (SFRs) called DPH and DPL, which should be accessible in 8-bit mode, see [here](http://keil.com/support/man/docs/is51/is51_ov_cpu8051variants.htm) and [here](http://slideshare.net/thandaiah/8051-microcontroller-notes-continuo%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bus) (starting page 20).